# Why can't I bind events to the elements in a namespace?

Tags: javascript, events, xml-namespaces

I have the following code and I want to listen to a mouseclick event but nothing will happen in this case why?

```
function Obj(tag){
  this.el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML",tag);
  this.el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("cccc"));
  this.el.onclick = function(){
    alert("onclick");
  }
}
var x = new Obj("mi");
document.body.appendChild(x.el);
```

Comment: Works fine in Chrome and FF: http://jsfiddle.net/wCHUa/

Comment: Which browser are you testing with?

Comment: I have firefox 21.0 and it is not working

Comment: Ahh, it is working in 20.0.1 though..

Comment: So is it a bug? or something

Comment: Just a sec, checking in 21.0...

Comment: Hmm.. looks like a bug to me.. Can't see a reason for this not working in 21.0.. And could find any related docs even.. You can perhaps post this as a bug in FF..